# What is #shadow-root, and why does it put display none on my font awesome classes?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, shadow-dom

Why does the shadow-root styles put display none on my `.fa-xxx` classes?

The shadow-root thing adds the classes I use to a display none pile, but only the specific ones I add!

I'm using PHP to include navigation, footers and such, but these don't get effected by it. For example it works just fine in my navigation. There it displays the font just fine.

What is causing this, and how do I control it?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you post the part of your original source code where it creates the shadow root inside?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have **AdBlock** extension installed? That might hide your elements.

Comment: Yes i do, and turning it off did the trick! Is there any way to get around this, besides putting _display:block !important_ on everything?

Comment: Well, AdBlock hides all elements that contain `ad` in their class or id. Here is a [hack](http://blog.kotowicz.net/2012/03/chrome-addons-hacking-bye-bye-adblock.html), although I've never tried it.  BUT, as a best practice, you should rename your classes and id's instead of using methods like the above

Comment: Hmm, okay, im not about to go change all of font-awesome´s class´s. I´ll just use the unicode instead, that seems to work.

And just for the record, im not using any class´s with `ad` in it. It is targeting the specific `fa-something` on that page. 

The even stranger thing is that it is not effecting the included documents like the navigation!

But nice to know this is an issue I need to be aware of in the future.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your main `section` has class `ad`d-top-shadow :)

Comment: That didn't do it either! it seems to be the specific social media class´s like `fa-facebook`, `fa-twitter`, `fa-linkedin` and `fa-pinterest`. Others like `fa-gamepad` work just fine.

Comment: ahh yes... FontAwesome's [suggested workaround](http://fontawesome.io/icons/#brand) is to change the class names

Comment: Jep, just found it. Renamed the effected classes to this `.my-fa-linkedin:before { content: "\f0e1"; }` and it works :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81664/discussion-between-razvan-balosin-and-jens-nielsen).