# Why is #shadow-root in my document and why is it overriding my CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

First, I've seen the duplicates

[What is #shadow-root, and why does it put display none on my font awesome classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31076278/what-is-shadow-root-and-why-does-it-put-display-none-on-my-font-awesome-classe)

and

[HTML / CSS - DIV Element hidden when it shouldn't be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465950/html-css-div-element-hidden-when-it-shouldnt-be)

however both of these suggest the issue is with adblock and I have totally disabled adblock.

I am more concerned with where the #shadow-root is coming from, since I certainly did not put it there.

I have read that there is an option in chrome to disable it (and interestingly enough I have it disabled...), but this means that anyone using my website will need to do the same, and I'd rather just do away with it entirely as it provides zero usefulness in my application.

I have also googled and read many of articles about the shadow dom and none of them give any insight on why it would appear seemingly for no reason.

From what I have seen in inspector/view page source, the entire contents of my app are being rendered into this shadow dom and thereby not receiving any of my styles.

I am using rails, react, redux, react-redux, react-router

Chrome developer tool screen
[image]

Page Source screen
[image]

Notice that the source has nothing in the div that react should be rendering to.

Additional info:
displays unstyled page on chrome in normal and incognito

does not work at all in safari

Comment: Can you provide a live example, or a screenshot of what you're seeing? Are you seeing the same thing in an incognito tab?

Comment: What is that `#shadow-root`? A CSS selector? An HTML with `id="shadow-root`?

Comment: ...but are you seeing `#shadow-root` in dev tools in an incognito tab?

Comment: Bryan I edited with screens, the most unusual part is how in page source the div container is empty when this is where react should be rendering to

Comment: That's actually not weird at all. React renders things with JavaScript. Viewing the raw source code for a page is just showing you what is in the raw HTML (before any JS executes). That's why viewing page source, and the elements panel in dev tools show drastically different things — especially in any kind of single page app. I suspect a chrome extension is adding the `#shadow-root`, and your problem is actually something completely unrelated.

Comment: thanks for the info I did not know about the page source, thought it was more or less a snapshot of the pages html when it is requested.  You are right that the shadow root is caused by some add on, the problem must be unrelated.  now just need to figure out why react wont render in safari

Comment: Consider accepting Conor's answer, and opening a new question if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of chrome plugins automatically create this shadow root in your inspector. For example, ever since I downloaded Vimium, I've had a shadowroot div at the bottom of any page I've opened in chrome. It's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and found that it was Adblock Plus that was adding #shadow-root.  Thanks to the resources above I was able to assertain what the issue

Answer (score 0):

For me it was also an Adblocker (uBlock) and it was actually hiding part of the webpage I was making which showed imported tweets. Turning the adblocker off for my site fixed it.